# Displaying Bookshelf.js model in hbs view

Tags: express, handlebars.js, bookshelf.js

I'm new to Bookshelf.js and hbs and would appreciate your help with the following:

I want to pre-fill a handlebars.js view form with data from a Bookshelf.js model.

hbs won't let me use the Bookshelf get method to get the desired attribute value: e.g. {{user.get(age)}}

I converted the model to JSON but am not able to query a specific json attribute in hbs e.g. {{user.age}}.

**JSON**

```
{"id":1,"fullName":"Mike","password":"password","email":"mike@email.com","age":38,"gender":"male","created_at":1432736718951,"updated_at":1432736718951}
```

Do I have to create a helper to extract the attribute value from the model?

---

```
function getUserModel(req, res, next) {
  User.forge({id: req.user})
    .fetch()
    .then(function(user){
      req.model = user;
      return next()
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      debug("Error loading userId[%s]", req.user);
      return next(err);
    });
}

router.use(ensureAuthenticated)
  .use(getUserModel);

router.get('/', function handlePhotoUploadGet(req, res, next) {
  var callback = "http://" + req.headers.host + "/cloudinary_cors.html";
  var params = {return_delete_token: true, callback: callback,
    timestamp: cloudinary.utils.timestamp()};
  var dataFormData = cloudinary.utils.sign_request(params);

  res.render('photos/upload',
    { title: 'Photo upload',
      cloudinary: cloudinary,
      dataFormData: JSON.stringify(dataFormData),
      user: req.model } 
  );
});
```

---

```
<input type="text" name="age" aria-label="age" value="{{user.age}}" placeholder="age" class="radius {{#if errors.invalidAttributes.fullName}}error{{/if}}" />

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" aria-label="Male" id="male" {{#if_equal user.gender 'male'}}checked{{/if_equal}}><label for="male">Male</label>
```

Comment: Change this line: req.model = user; to this: req.model = user.toJSON();

Comment: I've updated my answer below, can you please accept it as solution so that this question will be marked as answered?

Comment: Thank your very much for your help. I'm marked the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to answer this question you need to provide the server-side code, to see what you push to response, and client side html as well. Please update your question.

Update:
Change this line:

`req.model = user; to this: req.model = user.toJSON();`

Comment: I'm pushing either a Bookshelf Model or a JSON.stringify representation of the model: